# Drag and Drop проверка блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-n-drop

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #div1,
    #div2 {
      float: left;
      width: auto;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

  </style>
  <script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("content", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var image = ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
      if (ev.target.id == document.getElementById(image).getAttribute('data-div')) {
        alert("");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));
      } else {
        alert("");
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" data-div="div1">
    <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/2.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" data-div="div1">
    <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/3.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" data-div="div1">
    <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/4.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" data-div="div2">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

В чем проблема, до этого работал перетаскивание в блок больше одного, сейчас почему то не лезит. Где ошибка? Тут с 1 до 3 в первый блок идут, а 4 в 2 блок. И как можно проверить все разом? Типа все на месте или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Присвойте img разные ID. У вас во всех элементах стоит ID = "drag1"

```js
    function allowDrop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("content", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var image = ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
      if (ev.target.id == document.getElementById(image).getAttribute('data-div')) {
        alert("");
              console.log(image)
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));
      } else {
        alert("");
      }
    }
```

```css
 #div1,
    #div2 {
      float: left;
      width: auto;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" data-div="div1">
    <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/2.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" data-div="div1">
    <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/3.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3" data-div="div1">
    <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/4.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag4" data-div="div2">
  </div>
```

Comment: А как можно сделать только один `alert` при нажатии чтобы проверял в той `div` попали или нет

Comment: Ну не понятно как может не тот блок попасть в div, если стоит проверка при добавлении). Как вариант, написать функцию, которая будет получать все элементы div и проверять тот ли у них data-div.